How to create a cumulative v-file-input in vuetify
I have a v-file-input that I assign some docs in . If a user wants to add some files to it and click to select the files it clears the previous values. I would prefer to allow the v-file-input to cumulatively add files and the only way to clear the values is to press the clearable icon.
                  <v-file-input
                    v-model="supportingDocumentsModel"
                    :show-size="1000"
                    color="primary"
                    label="Rate Supporting Documents"
                    placeholder="Select your supporting documents"
                    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-file"
                    prepend-icon=""
                    variant="outlined"
                    counter
                    comfortable
                    multiple
                    clearable
                  >
                    <template v-slot:selection="{ fileNames }">
                      <template v-for="(fileName) in fileNames" :key="fileName">
                        <v-chip
                          class="me-2"
                          color="blue-accent-4"
                          size="small"
                          label
                        >
                          {{ fileName }}
                        </v-chip>
                      </template>
                    </template>
                  </v-file-input>

To expand on Yoduh's answer to try and make this more dynamic:
const updateFiles = (files : File[], persistentFiles : File[]) => {
    //get new files by finding difference between persisted files and latest file selection
    const newFiles = files.filter(file1 => {
      return !persistentFiles.some(file2 => {
        return file1.name === file2.name
      })
    })
    // set new files to persist
    persistentFiles.push(...newFiles)
    // update v-model
    files = persistentFiles
}

function clearFiles(files : File[], persistentFiles : File[]) {
  persistentFiles = []
  files = []
}

This does not seem to work trying to pass the models and persistent models as parameters

persistentFiles.value.push not persistentFiles.push

Yea but when you pass a ref as a parameter do you still have to use .value?

The v-model dynamically updates based on the latest file selection, so you'll need to manually track what the previous items were so you can add always add them back to the v-model when it updates.
<v-file-input
  multiple
  v-model="files"
  clearable
  @update:model-value="updateFiles"
  @click:clear="clearFiles"
/>

const files = ref([])
const persistentFiles = ref([])

function updateFiles() {
  // get new files by finding difference between persisted files and latest file selection
  const newFiles = files.value.filter(file1 => {
    return !persistentFiles.value.some(file2 => {
      return file1.name === file2.name
    })
  })
  // set new files to persist
  persistentFiles.value.push(...newFiles)
  // update v-model
  files.value = persistentFiles.value
}

function clearFiles() {
  persistentFiles.value = []
  files.value = []
}

Vuetify Playground example
Edit:
For dynamic number of v-file-inputs, you could define files and persistentFiles each as array of arrays. Each v-file-input accesses its own array by using an index.
Vuetify Playground multiple v-file-inputs example

As always Yoduh thank you! My only question is if I have many of these v-file-inputs on the page is there a way to make this more dynamic so I do not need a separate updateFiles function and clearFiles function for every v-file-input?

I have included what i was thinking as an approach above based off yours. Does not seem to work passing the models as parameters. I just wanted to make this more flexible since I have about 10 of these file inputs

I for some reason cannot get this to work in a more dynamic approach. I have too many of these to create separate functions for each.

Hi, sorry for not getting back sooner.  I have edited my answer with a new idea at the bottom for handling multiple v-file-inputs

No worries I appreicate your help. I am just curious why does passing the ref/model variable as a parameter in my example of your code not work? Seemed like an interesting approach but whether I use .value or not the code does seem to function as yours does.
